# Swift: Cannot assign value '(Bool, MCSession) -> Void' to type '(Bool, MCSession!) -> Void!'

Tags: swift, bluetooth

Im trying [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/chat-app-swift-tutorial/) and because of the new swift version some errors came up, one of them was MPCManager does not conform with the protocol MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate.

I tried to fix it so i changed the header of func advertiser to this one:

> func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser,
>   didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context:
>   NSData?, invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession)->Void) {

but then it throws me an error

> Cannot assign value '(Bool, MCSession) -> Void' to type '(Bool,
>   MCSession!) -> Void!'

which i don't know how to fix, help appreciated!

The actual file:

```
    import UIKit
    import MultipeerConnectivity

    protocol MPCManagerDelegate {
        func foundPeer()

        func lostPeer()

        func invitationWasReceived(fromPeer: String)

        func connectedWithPeer(peerID: MCPeerID)
    }

    class MPCManager: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate {
        var session: MCSession!
        var peer: MCPeerID!
        var browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!
        var advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!

        var foundPeers = [MCPeerID]()
        var invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession!)->Void!
        var delegate: MPCManagerDelegate?

        override init() {
            super.init()

            invitationHandler(false, nil)

            peer = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)

            session = MCSession(peer: peer)
            session.delegate = self

            browser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: peer, serviceType: "appcoda-mpc")
            browser.delegate = self

            advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peer, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "appcoda-mpc")
            advertiser.delegate = self
        }

        func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
            foundPeers.append(peerID)

            delegate?.foundPeer()
        }

        func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
            for (index, aPeer) in EnumerateSequence(foundPeers){
                if aPeer == peerID {
                    foundPeers.removeAtIndex(index)
                    break
                }
            }

            delegate?.lostPeer()
        }

        func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, didNotStartBrowsingForPeers error: NSError) {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ THE Error occurs here: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: NSData?, invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession)->Void) {
            self.invitationHandler = invitationHandler

            delegate?.invitationWasReceived(peerID.displayName)
        }

        func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didNotStartAdvertisingPeer error: NSError) {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }



        func session(session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {
            switch state{
            case MCSessionState.Connected:
                print("Connected to session: \(session)")
                delegate?.connectedWithPeer(peerID)

            case MCSessionState.Connecting:
                print("Connecting to session: \(session)")

            default:
                print("Did not connect to session: \(session)")
            }
        }

        func sendData(dictionaryWithData dictionary: Dictionary<String, String>, toPeer targetPeer: MCPeerID) -> Bool {
            let dataToSend = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dictionary)
            let peersArray = NSArray(object: targetPeer) as! [MCPeerID]

            do {
                _ = try session.sendData(dataToSend, toPeers: peersArray, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return false
            }

            return true
        }

        func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
            let dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = ["data": data, "fromPeer": peerID]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("receivedMPCDataNotification", object: dictionary)
        }

        func session(session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withProgress progress: NSProgress) { }

        func session(session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, atURL localURL: NSURL, withError error: NSError?) { }

        func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) { }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please put the snippets of the problematic code into your question?

Comment: Edited! What about now?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the `invitationHandler` variable with `(Bool, MCSession!)->Void!` type, then assign it with a value `(Bool, MCSession)->Void)` type. This is the reason which causes your error message.

To fix it, define your `advertiser` method with the param match type with the `invitationHandler` variable.

Comment: If i do that, i displays the first error again, MPCManager doesn't conform with the protocol MCNearbyServiceAdvertizerDelegate

Comment: I see. So, you must change the type of `invitationHandler` match with definition in the `advertiser` method.

Comment: Tried that, then it throws an error invitationHandler must be initilized in the init func, how do i initilize such a var?

Comment: Try this `var invitationHandler:((Bool, MCSession)->Void)?`

Answer (score 0):

The property `invitationHandler` of the class `MPCManager` is defined as:

```
var invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession!) -> Void!
```

... while the argument `invitationHandler` of `advertiser` method is defined as

```
invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession) -> Void
```

There are 2 mismatches here:

- Property's return value is `Void!` while argument returns `Void`
- Second argument of the property is `MCSession!` while method takes `MCSession`

Firstly, I do not see the point to have `Void!` as return value.  `Void` means nothing is being returned at all, so no need to implicitly unwrap it.

Secondly, the argument's types must match.  So, either both should be `MCSession` or both `MCSession!`.

E.g. the following does not produce the error you mention:

```
var invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession!) -> Void

// ...

func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: NSData?, 
    invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession!) -> Void) {
```